# Sonar in Maven build stopped working

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I had a project built with maven on a Jenkins CI server, and recently the Sonar portion of the build began to fail with the well known

```
  org.sonar.core.persistence.BadDatabaseVersion: Database must be upgraded. Please browse http://x.x.x.x:9000/setup
```

I browsed to http://x.x.x.x:9000/setup, and the message there was green and said my database was up to date.  The database looks good and the sonar server doesn't throw any Exceptions as far as I can tell from the output, and this installation had been working well up until a few days ago.

I checked that the id was the same between the running server and the database, and insured that only one instance of Sonar was talking to the H2 DB.

My next step is to step through Sonar code, which I'm not eager to do.   Any pointers as to what's wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this doesn't address your question directly, but you should seriously consider hosting your Sonar database in something other than H2. I've done this on one project and after a couple of days Sonar analysis time went up from 1 to 5 minutes and it was getting worse by the day :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, is your Maven plugin version aligned with your Sonar install?

Comment: @Spiff -- that is it.  I hadn't set the sonar plugin version in the pom, and about a week ago maven picked up 3.6-RC1, while my server was still running 3.5.1.  Simple fix, frustrating error message though.  If you put your comment as the answer, I'm happy to select it.

Comment: Glad to see it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Maven plugin version is probably not aligned with your Sonar install.